# jquery-ui Drag with mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

As you know when we use jquery-ui draggable, we can drag our elements with mouse left click. For a specific element of mine, I want to drag it with mouse scroll button. How can I make this happen?

Comment: I guess you look for something like http://jsfiddle.net/mz4dbhps/